# ¿Como incluir archivos css o javascript solo en paginas especificas usando PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, css

Hola quiza alguien me pueda ayudar con esta duda. Quisiera saber como podria hacer para incluir distintos archivos css dependiendo de la pagina. Voy a poner un ejemplo para tratar de explicarme mejor.

Tengo una web basica con sus correspondientes header.php y footer.php
En el header tengo lo basico

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"><!-- primer archivo css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom-style.css"><!-- segundo archivo css -->
    <title>Mi pagina</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        Cabecera
    </header>
```

El footer lo tengo asi

```
    <footer>
        Pie de pagina
    </footer>
    <script src="/app1.js"></script><!-- primer archivo js -->
    <script src="/app2.js"></script><!-- segundo archivo js -->
</body>

</html>
```

Finalmente en el index.php hago un include para llamar al header y footer

```
<?php
include("./header.php") 
?>
<main>
    Contenido principal
</main>
<?php
include("./footer.php") 
?>
```

Ahora si en header.php y footer.php coloco los css y js globales, es decir que seran usados en todo el sitio. **¿Como podria hacer para incluir nuevos archivos css y js en paginas especificas?**

Es decir si creo una nueva pagina: pagina-secundaria.php, ¿cual seria la forma de poner un archivo de css o js adicional solo en esta pagina teniendo en cuenta que usaria la misma estructura del index?

```
//solo en esta pagina quiero añadir css o js adicional
<?php
include("./header.php") 
?>
<main>
    Contenido principal
</main>
<?php
include("./footer.php") 
?>
```

Lo eh pensado mucho pero no me queda claro.

Comment: Me parece que no es buena idea poner cada mitad del documento en un archivo diferente ya que te llevas partes esenciales del HTML (las etiquetas html, head y body). Yo pondría solo la parte de la etiqueta `header` dentro del archivo `header.php` y la parte de la etiqueta `footer` en `footer.php`.

Comment: También puedes introducir tus hojas de estilo  y scripts en cualquier parte válida de tu documento, no tiene porqué estar todo exactamante dentro de la etiqueta `<header>` y `<footer>`. En fin, que hay muchas opiniones al respecto. Supongo que a los de SEO no les gusta mucho mi idea. Saludos

Comment: @Mateo depende de lo que estes haciendo; si estas trabajando con paginas estaticas; es importante mantener todo el html en un solo archivo; pero el escenario presentado no es ese... lo que el chico esta plantenado es el uso de pseudo plantillas para reciclar contenido y codigo en pro de las vistas de las pagina... es normal seccionar el codigo html por bloques y llevarlo a archivos individuales...

Comment: tambien existen otros metodo como el armado progresivo ... para evitar el uso de plantillas o tener que generar un mundo de plantillas...

Comment: Mauricio Contreras si pensaba lo mismo en que podria incluirlo en cualquier parte del html. Pero igual tengo mis dudas de cara al seo.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 donde podria encontrar mas informacion sobre armado progresivo que mencionas?

Comment: @FerDaniela no lo vas a encontrar, el armado progresivo es un concepto cuando tienes un analizador de contenido que llama a los metodos para ir armando el output segun la necesidad y la estructura/arquitectura de tu sitio web, sin requerir en teoria plantillas estaticas pero si plantillas dinamicas: https://i.imgur.com/R3i6Q4O.png muy similar a MVC pero orientado a la funcionalidad del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

En pagina-secundaria.php podrías usar una variable para un `if`:

```
<?php
$pag_actual = "secundaria";
include("./header.php") 
?>
<main>
    Contenido principal
</main>
<?php
include("./footer.php") 
?>
```

Y en el header usar el `if`:

```
if ($pag_actual == "secundaria") {
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css-personalizado.css">';
} else {
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">';
}
```

Comment: gracias parece buena opcion, pero me pongo a pensar sera un poco si en lugar de una sola pagina fueran digamos 10 que necesiten de un css o javascript especifico.